# How to understand `{'key: function('1')}` in VimScript？

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

Rescently I am in favor of a Vim plugin called [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim). a dict named as `g:bundle` has a item:

```
{'path': function('1')}
```

If I call the item.path(), Vundle can invoke "s:bundle.path()" in vundle/config.vim :

```
func! s:bundle.path()
    return s:expand_path(g:bundle_dir.'/'.self.name)
endf
```

So, could you tell me the usage about **parameter "1" of anonymous function** in Vimscript?

---

**Updated:**

Thanks for Mr. Karkat.

I use `:function {1}` command, whose result is:

```
function 1() dict                                                                                                                                                          
    return s:expand_path(g:bundle_dir.'/'.self.name)
endfunction
```

the function block is same as `s:bundle.path()`, it proves that number in braces means `Funcref`:

> The function will then get a nusmber and the value of dict.len is a
>   Funcref  that references this function. The function can only be used
>   through a Funcref. It will automatically be deleted when there is no
>   Funcref   remaining that refers to it.

**Referance:**

> https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/blob/master/autoload/vundle/config.vim#L106
>   http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#Dictionary-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is an [anonymous Dictionary function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#numbered-function). What this means is that for the Dictionary `{'path': function('1')}` (let's call it `foo`, and we know that it's an element of `g:bundles`), there has been defined this:

```
let foo = {}
function foo.path() dict
    return "foo"
endfunction
```

You can find out more about the function definition via

```
:function {1}
```

Comment: Thinks, but I can't find the `definition function 1() dict` in source,  which block is same as `s:bundle.path()`'s. These are related via `{'path': function('1')}` ?

Comment: I don't see the connection of `s:bundle.path()` to `g:bundles` (with `s`, and a List, not what you've written in your question).

Comment: I add the detail to the body of question just then.